# Geofence on current user location

Tags: android, iphone, android-geofence

I am currently studying a possible project on Android and iPhone.
I need to know if geofences could help me, or if another method should be used.
I think the geofence are not used in this way but I ask anyway.
Is it possible to place a geofence on the current user location (even if it moves)  and sending messages when other people come on the geofence position (even they are 100 000) ? 
Thank you very much in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's do-able but you will be lagging a lot...you will have to get a strong server to get all the positions of the users at a given time and place a listener on each user location s.t. in case his geolocation gets into some geofence every listener should inform its listenee (which will probable be the user class), so far should be good BUT hypothetically 1 user can get into millions other geofences (indicating your start-up is running quite good...) which will require the server to send millions of alert, now think on a million users moving - that means that even if you send just their location you can end up moving a couple of tera-bytes in a second to the server and from it plus requiring it to make more than trillions actions (probabley push notifications?) per second...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many variables as: radius of your geofences, quantity of users, etc. Notice, that in normal life you never approach 100000 people at one time, well, maybe at the football game. I think nothing is impossible, but a lot of factors need to be reviewed.